# WHERE Column IN from parameter in DB2 over SSIS

Tags: ssis, db2, sql-like, where-clause, sql-in

I want to do the following command in a SSIS Package to DB2.

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
    SET Col1 = ?,
        Col2 = ?
WHERE Col3 IN (?)
```

The Parameters are connected and the package is finished successfully but no row is updated. The Col3 contains values like `123`, `452` and so on and the third parameter is a string with a content like `345,432,456,432,667,123,456`.

What have I to change to be able to update the rows?

I tried it with the following. In SQL Server it would work but in DB2 not.

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
    SET Col1 = ?,
        Col2 = ?
WHERE ? LIKE '%' CONCAT Col3 CONCAT '%'
```

**Edit**

The value in the third Parameter is `'345','432','456','432','667','123','456'`. The content in Col3 is also a string.

Comment: Check my answer update

Answer (score 2):

You have an ability to "tokenize" the string passed as a parameter.

```
UPDATE MyTable m
    SET Col1 = ?,
        Col2 = ?
WHERE Col3 IN
(
  select TOKEN
  from xmltable
  (
  'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
  passing cast (? as varchar(100)) as "s"
  columns 
    TOKEN integer path 'if (. castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer(.) else ()'
  ) t
);
```

The `subselect` in the `WHERE` clause produces a "virtual" table of `int` values from a string (for example, `345,432,456,432,667,123,456`) passed as a 3-rd parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting all the values in a single string and SQL thinks it's one value `'345,432,456,432,667,123,456'`.

You will have to dynamically produce the list of in statements or if the number of rows to delete are constant, put in a separate variable for each row to delete.

Comment: For this solution I need dynamic SQL. If I have read it right I can do this only in a DB2 stored procedure and not inline. Is it correct or can I use dynamic SQL also in an inline command?

Answer (score 0):

You must use expressions to achieve that. Use SQL Command from variable and select a variable where you define a similar expression:

```
"UPDATE MyTable
    SET Col1 ='" +(DT_WSTR,50)@[User::Var1] +"' ,
        Col2 ='" +(DT_WSTR,50)@[User::Var2] +"'
WHERE Col3 IN (" + (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::Var3] + ")"
```

- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4564/ssis-variable-and-expression-example--part-1/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-ssis-expressions?view=sql-server-2017

---

From a while i didn't use SSIS with DB2, so if there is no `SQL Command from variable` optio. Click on the data flow task, press F4 to show the properties tab, go to expressions. In the expression form you will find `[OLEDB Source].SQLCommand` property you can write the expression there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it, if I continue to work on this project at the end of next week.